# What jellyfish is this?

Tags: species-identification

[image]
I saw this jellyfish at Brighton Beach, Victoria, Australia. I have searched jellyfish images but there is nothing similar. It is round with a diameter of approximately 80cm and the blue part looks like hundreds of thin tassels.

Comment: Please copy the picture to your post directly using the edit button and then pasting the link into the photo uploader. Thanks

Comment: diameter of 80 cm! are you sure you haven't done a typo

Comment: https://jellywatch.org/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Pseudorhiza haeckeli. Based on cross motif, and long tail. Grows over a metre across. There is a photo at https://www.abc.net.au/science/photos/2012/01/11/3406019.htm?xml=3406019.mediarss.xml#bigpicturepos
but dont copy it here - copyright.